# reformat a txt file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with this format:

```
A  B  C  D  E  F
```

I want to change it in this way:

```
B  A:D
```

and get rid of other columns.

Answer (score 6):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{print $2,$1":"$4}' file.txt
```

Comment: that was fast!...thank you very much!